# $f_n(x) = \cos \left( \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n} }\right)$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I need to prove that this sequence of functions:

$$f_n(x) = \cos \left( \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n} }\right)$$

converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

This is a question regarding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586933/uniform-convergence-of-f-nx-cos-left-sqrtx2-frac1n-right-o?rq=1) one. There's an answer that suggests these hints:

$$\cos\alpha-\cos\beta=-2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-x=\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\tag{1}$$

in order to prove that, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0$ such that, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$n>n_0 \implies \sup\left|\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\right)-\cos(x)\right|<\epsilon$$
I did the following:

If I prove that such $n_0$ always exists, I can prove that this sequence converges uniformly (or not). By the hints he gave, we have:

$$\left|\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\right)-\cos(x)\right| = \left|2\sin\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-x}}{2}\sin\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x}}{2}\right|\le 2\sin\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\sin\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\to 0$$

*the last $\le$ symbol holds because $\sin$ is crescent from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but how $x\in [0,1]$ guarantee that the following will happen? Also, what if $x>1$ or $x<0$? Don't inequality $(1)$ holds for all $x$?

So since $\left|\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\right)-\cos(x)\right|$ is always greater than $0$ but we proved here it's $\le 0$, we have that $\sup$ of this sequence of absolute values is $0$. We haven't touched $n_0$ so far, neither $\epsilon$. Is it because the inequalities used hold for large $n$ and we always have $0<\epsilon$?. Therefore, I proved that this sequence converges uniformly.

Extra: also, does $\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ holds because:

$$n\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x\right)\ge \sqrt{n}\implies LHS^{-1}\le RHS^{-1}$$

?

I think that since $n>\sqrt{n}$ for $n>1$ (we're intersted in large values of $n$), we have that $n\cdot \mbox{something}>\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Sorry but the inequality $$\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-x}}{2}\leqslant\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$ cannot hold for every $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @did do you know how to do the $\sin(a+b)$ then?

Comment: @did well, I can use the fact that $\sin(a+b)$ is limited, and the other $\sin()$ is going to $0$, right???

Comment: Exactly: (bounded) times (going to zero) makes (going to zero).

Comment: @did so my proof is right? How can I guarantee that the last $\ge$ sign is true? I just have an inuition. Also, my proof of the inequality suggested as hint is wrong, do yoi have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but your post is now quite a mess, unnecessarily complicated, so let us try to decompose the proof. First step: using the notation $f(x)=\cos x$, $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leqslant2|\sin g_n(x)|\leqslant g_n(x),$$ with $$ g_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1/n}-|x|.$$ Second step: $$g_n(x)=\frac{1/n}{\sqrt{x^2+1/n}+|x|}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{n}}.$$ Third step (conclusion): $$\|f_n-f\|_\infty\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{n}},\ \text{qed}.$$ If any step somehow still causes problems, please say so. (Note that this proves that the convegence is uniform on $\mathbb R$, not only $[0,1]$.)

Comment: *Correction: $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leqslant2\,|\sin(\frac12g_n(x))|\leqslant g_n(x)$.

Comment: @did nice, but why did $-|x|$ turn into $+|x|$? Also, my proof is the same but with $\sin$ going to $0$, right? Does my proof work for all reals too?

Comment: @did shouldn't it be $\sin^2()$? Because its $2$ sines multiplying

Comment: @did where's the proof that $n_0$ only depends on $\epsilon$?

Comment: First question: why $-|x|$ turn into $+|x|$? The question is not clear but might allude to the algebraic identity $$\sqrt{x^2+c}-|x|=\frac{c}{\sqrt{x^2+c}+|x|}.$$ Second question: why not $\sin^2$? Definitely not. The difference of cosines is $$\cos u-\cos v=-2\sin((u+v)/2)\sin((-uv)/2),$$ then one uses the bounds $$|\sin((u+v)/2)|\leqslant1\qquad|\sin((u-v)/2)|\leqslant|u-v|/2.$$ Third question: there you ask me to deduce from the third step $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\leqslant1/\sqrt{n}$, an explicit index $n_0$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\leqslant\epsilon$ for every ...

Comment: @did could you take a look? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1818050/why-this-proof-of-f-nx-cos-left-sqrtx2-frac1n-right-unifor i'm having difficulties in the part that why $n_0$ depends only on $\epsilon$. Is it simply because the inequality holds for all $x$? And why proving that it goes to $0$ proves that it converges?

Comment: ... $n\geqslant n_0$. Hmmm... Can I avoid to comment on the fact that you are asking this? And delicately suggest to reread all this with a pen in hand? Then I do.

Comment: @did sorry, I didn't understand your comment

Comment: Which one? The one suggesting to grab a pen *and start checking the solution in my comments*? Too bad.

Comment: And now, *two* deliberate duplicates? Sorry but you are starting to push all the wrong buttons, it seems.

Comment: *Typo: The unique occurrence of $\sin((-uv)/2)$ above should read $\sin((u-v)/2)$, of course.

Comment: @did i understood your solution, I checked the identity that turns $-x$ to $|x|$, it's because of the 'conjugate' multiplication. I understood that you made it smaller that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, I was just asking: how does that proves that given any $\epsilon$, the $n_0$ will not depend on $x$. Is it because all inequalities above work for any $x$ in $[0,\infty)$? Also, I asked for you to take a look at my proof because it was the most natural way it came to me, I just needed to see if my thinking is right. I was trying to use the uniform convergence of a function that is already proved inbook

Comment: so my teacher would accept it. If I say that such function converges uniformly because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ does, I don't know if she'll accept. By the way, sorry for being so intrusive :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different idea: The mean value theorem gives $\cos b - \cos a = -\sin c\cdot(b-a),$ which implies $|\cos b - \cos a| \le |b-a|.$ Thus

$$|\cos \sqrt {x^2+1/n} - \cos x| \le |\sqrt {x^2+1/n} - x|.$$

So we need only show $\sqrt {x^2+1/n} \to x$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ For this it's good to know that if $a,b \ge 0,$ then $\sqrt {a+b} \le \sqrt a + \sqrt b.$ (Square both sides to see this.) Thus

$$ x < \sqrt {x^2+1/n} \le x + 1/\sqrt n.$$

This implies $0 < \sqrt {x^2+1/n} - x \le 1/\sqrt n,$ and we're done. (In fact we have shown uniform convergence on $ [0,\infty).$)

Comment: You don't often see an answer checked and get a negative score.