# proof of $\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for large $n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to conclude [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816739/f-nx-cos-left-sqrtx2-frac1n-right-is-uniformly-convergent) in which I just need to prove that:

$$0<\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

and then I'll have that, for large $n$:

$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert\cos\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\right)-\cos(x)\right\rvert &= \left\lvert2\sin\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-x}{2}\sin\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x}}{2}\right\rvert\\
&\leq
2\sin\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-x}{2}\sin\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
\end{align}$$

because $\sin\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\to 0$ and $\sin\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-x}{2}$ is bounded.

I liked the answers given in the question but I really need to solve it this way, I'm trying to investigate the inequation. I know that, the worst case is for $n$ so large that $\frac{1}{n}$ in the LHS of the inequality goes to $0$, and the best case is when $n=1$ and therefore we have:

$$\sqrt{x^2}+x<\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}+x<\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\le\sqrt{2}+1$$

*for $0\le x\le 1$

but it doesn't help, I think.

Comment: Well, as $x$ is positive, by monotonicity $\sqrt{x^2+1/n}+x \geq \sqrt{x^2+1/n}+\geq \sqrt{1/n}$... and then your inequality follows

Comment: I'm not sure you need monotonicity, @b00nheT. At any rate, your use of the positivity of $x$ is surely the simplest solution.

Comment: You do need the monotonicity of the square root, do you not? I see I had forgot to write which monotonicity, I have included that in my answer below. And thank you ;)

Comment: The displayed "=" is as wrong as can be, as explained on the page this one is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as $x$ is positive, by monotonicity of the square root
$$\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}+x \geq \sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}+\geq \sqrt{\frac1n}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$$
Thus
$$\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}+x}\leq \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac1n}}\leq \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: this is valid for any $x$ and any $n$, right? So the uniform convergence is in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Most definitely, as long as $x\ge 0$ for the very first step

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** setting $\alpha=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, you want to prove
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+\alpha^2}+x} \leq \frac{1}{\alpha}, \qquad \forall x\geq 0\tag{1}
$$
Let us prove it for all $\alpha > 0$: this will then be equivalent to proving that for all $x\geq 0$
$$
\sqrt{x^2+\alpha^2}+x \geq \alpha, \qquad \forall x\geq 0
$$
that is, removing $x$ from each side and squaring, this will be equivalent* to showing that
$$
x^2+\alpha^2 \geq x^2+\alpha^2 - 2\alpha x, \qquad \forall x\geq 0.
$$

Now, why is that the case?

---

${}$* You may want to check that this is indeed equivalent, since we square... but yes, it is, as if the original RHS is negative then there is nothing to prove (the LHS is always positive).

Answer (score 1):

Cross-multiply, square, subtract ${1\over n}$ from both sides to get
$$
0\le 2x^2+2x\sqrt{x^2+{1\over n}}
$$
Assuming $x\in[0,1]$ the above identity is trivial as each term on the RHS is non-negative. Now backtrack and get your desired identity.